# Call ESP8266 SDK API function on SMING framework application

Tags: wifi, esp8266, sming

I am using ESP8266 WiFi chip and the SMING framework.

I would like to call SDK API function inside an app that uses the SMING framework.

Suppose I want to call `wifi_station_set_reconnect_policy(true)`. How can I do this in a SMING application.cpp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMING is just a layer above the SDK, you can call it directly.

The method `wifi_station_set_reconnect_policy` is defined in the `user_interface.h` of the SDK, then you can call it in your `application.cpp` like this :

```
#include <user_config.h>
#include <SmingCore/SmingCore.h>

void init()
{
    wifi_station_set_reconnect_policy(true);
}
```